# Cant connect to Oracle from DBeaver in Windows 10 pro

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

While trying to connect to Oracle 18C(express edition) from Dbeaver 7.2.0 in Windows 10 Pro (I m using the password that I set during Oracle installation), I am getting the error:

**connection refused, IO ERROR:Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

[image]

JDBC Driver is downloaded as well

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to log in before? Is the TMS Listener running? If so, try to running the `tnspng` command and update your question with the output of that command.

Comment: I m new in Oracle, no idea about tnsping. I couldnt login before, this is the first time

Comment: The `tnsping` (ugh -- now I see my typo on that command name in my previous comment, and TMS Listener should be TNS Listener process...) should be available in the ORACLE_HOME\bin directory, and when you open up a command prompt in that directory and run it, it will attempt to connect to the database via the network configuration that you set up.  The database does not need to be up and running to use that command, but you will get more accurate results if at least the TNS Listener is running.  I imagine either your TNS Listener is not running, and/or some Oracle network config issue.

Comment: tnsping is working but what command to run on that? I didnt make any database yet.

Comment: Now I m getting the error- "Listener refused the connection with the following error:

"ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor "Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"

I followed a youtube tutorial as in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQvWxM3c02g

Comment: Take a look at these questions https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btnsnames%5D+windows  and also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+%5Btnsnames%5D+windows+10

Comment: @Tanvir I was in same ORA-12514 error. I started OracleServiceORCL windows service and same error again. But it was my mistake. OracleServiceORCL service was not running immediately, it takes 1 minute to run. After completed to running, I successed to connect.